# Bind button/links with my carousel images in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, carousel

In my application there is a carousel with images that I get from my service. Under the carousel there are 3 buttons that give more information about the image.

[image]

These information buttons should replace the bullet indicators for a standard carousel. The buttons get an active class when the corresponding image is displayed so it stands out from the other 2.

Below is my code, I'm using this [carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel)

```
        <ul rn-carousel>
            <li ng-repeat="promo in promos">
               <img ng-src="{{ promo.slider[0].slide }}" alt="{{ promo.name }}">
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div ng-repeat="promo in promos">
            <button>
               <h2>{{ promo.name }}</h2>
               <p>- {{ promo.descr }} <span>{{ promo.disc }}</span></p>
            </button>
        </div>
```

I have no problems getting the info out of my service, it's just the linking part that is giving me problems.

Comment: Please specify your question. If you want to display the specific slide when a button get's pressed, usage rn-carousel-index attribute.
`<ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-index="currentSlide">` 

and `<button ng-click="currentSlide = $index">`

Comment: Not only when the button is pressed but when the slide changes the active class goes to the corresponding button

Comment: Also, the fix you gave me for when I press on the buttons isn't working

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle and clarify what behavior you want to achieve.

Css Classes may be added to the buttons using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive, e.g. `ng-class="{'activeButton': $index === currentSlide}"`

Comment: Here's the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5mLvnher/) the carousel isn't working in the fiddle, it's my first time using jsfiddle so maybe I did something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after searching through the issues page of the carousel I'm using.

```
    <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-index="currentSlide">
        <li ng-repeat="promo in promos">
           <img ng-src="{{ promo.slider[0].slide }}" alt="{{ promo.name }}">
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-repeat="promo in promos">
        <button ng-class="{activeBtn: $index==$parent.currentSlide}" ng-click="$parent.currentSlide = $index">
           <h2>{{ promo.name }}</h2>
           <p>- {{ promo.descr }} <span>{{ promo.disc }}</span></p>
        </button>
    </div>
```

I had to name my carousel-index and for my indicators I had to refer to the parent element for the binding to work.

Thanks to [Capricorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225619/capricorn) for leading the way.